# VBA macro using vlookup when a certain value is entered in cell. Needs to work for an entire column

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

Here is the details of my request:

1. Column "F" in Sheet1 is named "Classification".
2. Column "I" in Sheet1 is named "Expected Time"
3. Sheet2 has a table where Column "A" is a list of all Classifications and Column "B" has associated times to each Classification.
4. I would like to have a macro that would vlookup the time associated to a classification that is entered in column "F" on Sheet1 by referencing the table on Sheet2.
5. Basically, any classification entered in column "F" in sheet1 should result in an auto-population of the time in Column "I" in sheet1.

I copied the function in column "I" for the whole column but when I open the file it loads up very slow. To avoid this I am looking for a macro that will work only when an entry is made in column "F" in sheet1.

I hope this explains what I am trying to achieve.

This is the code I am using:

```
Dim sheet As Worksheet 
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Report") 
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sheet1.Range("F4"), sheet2.Range("A:B"), 2, False)
```

I don't get any errors. Nothing happens when I enter a value into a cell in Column "F".

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service. Yet we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You might also want to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and earn a badge while doing so. Afterwards, please update your question with the VBA code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. We will be here waiting for you. Ready to assist and help you finalize *your code*.

Comment: This is what I tried but doesn't work:Dim result As String 
Dim sheet As Worksheet 
Set sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Daily Report") 
result = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(sheet1.Range("F4"), sheet2.Range("A:B"), 4, False)

Comment: I don't get any errors. Nothing happens when I enter a value into a cell in Column "F"

Comment: I have updated the question with the code that I am using.

Comment: Was that code in the `Worksheet_Change` event?  What did you do with the variable `result` after you calculated it?  (Did you place the value into a cell, or is that the end of your subroutine?)

Comment: `Nothing happens when I enter a value into a cell in Column "F".` What do you think should happen?

Comment: I am novice at this so don;t know what you are referring to. Maybe I should just find a site that will write me the code.

Comment: People get paid for that sort of thing.

Comment: There it is below for FREE for the next person like me that is looking for help.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("C:C")) Is Nothing Then
            With Target(1, 0)
                .Value = Now
                .EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End With
        End If

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J:J")) Is Nothing Then
            With Target(1, 2)
                .Value = Now
                .EntireColumn.AutoFit
            End With
        End If

        If Not Intersect(Target, Range("F:F")) Is Nothing And Target.Row > 3 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Target.Offset(0, 3).Formula = "=Iferror(Vlookup(" & Target.Address & ",'Digital Services'!C:F,4,0),"""")"
            Target.Offset(0, 3).Value = Target.Offset(0, 3).Value
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
End Sub
```